# thymeleaf how to get an input backing bean generated name attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Is it possible with thymeleaf to retrieve an input "generated" name attribute ?

I need to create a div with an id equals to an input name attribute.
Input names are generated via the th:field.

Markup:

`<input type="radio" id="winterTiresInstalled" th:field="*{winterTiresInstalled.value}" />`

Generated markup:

`<input id="fld_winterTires" type="radio" name="vehicle.winterTiresInstalled.value" />`

What I want :

`<div th:id="???" />`

to obtain :

`<div id="vehicle.winterTiresInstalled.value" />`

So, how can I retrieve the generated name attribute value "vehicle.winterTiresInstalled.value" with thymleaf ?

I could do it in js but I would prefer doing it in my template.

Thank you.
David

Comment: The name attribute seems to be generated by the class SpringInputRadioFieldAttrProcessor.doProcess method (String name = bindStatus.getExpression();). How can we retrieve the spring-mvc bindStatus in thymeleaf ?

Comment: Using thymeleaf 2.1.4.RELEASE  and spring-mvc  4.3.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

`th-attr` is best suited for this use case.

```
<a href="#" th:attr="data-id=${object.getId()}, data-name=${object.getName()}"/>
```

The above will result is something like this(haven't tested)

```
<a href="#" data-id="420" data-name="user-link"/>
```

Comment: I don't have access to a getName method.  I don't have control on how the name attribute is generated on my inputs. It's seems to be generated by spring-mvc BindStatus. It's uses the backing bean path to generate the name.   I would like to access the  bindStatus.getExpression() with thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0):

Did the solution in javascript for now. I change the id of div after the page loads.
I would prefer do it directly in my template but can't figure out a way to do it with thymeleaf.